# Evaluation of $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(\ln{x})^s} \, dx$

Tags: integration, limits, improper-integrals

I am revising my maths and a bit rusty on what approach I need to use to solve this...

I'm pretty sure it should converge and I can't figure out where I have gone wrong!

I have tried 2 different approaches which both lead to the same answer.

### Attempt 1: Substitution (First)

$$I = \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(\ln{x})^s}dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int^{t}_{1}\frac{(\ln{x})^{-s}}{x}dx$$

let $u = \ln{x}$ and let $du = \frac{1}{x}dx$,

$$I \to \lim_{t\to\infty}\int^{t}_{1}u^{-s}du = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\frac{u^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]^{t}_{1}$$

$$ = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{x})^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]^{t}_{1}$$

$$ = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{t})^{1-s}}{1-s} - \frac{(\ln{1})^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]$$

$$ = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{t})^{1-s}}{1-s} - 0\right]$$

- $s<1$ : $I \to \infty$
- $s=1$ : $I$ is undefined
- $s>1$ : $I \to \infty$

### Attempt 2: Integration by Parts (First)

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x(\ln{x})^s}dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int^{t}_{1}\frac{1}{x(\ln{x})^s}dx$$

$$ I = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int^{t}_{1}{x^{-1}(\ln{x})^{-s}}dx$$
Integration by parts:
$$\int{u}{dv} = uv - \int{v}{du}$$

$$u = (\ln{x})^{-s} \qquad dv = x^{-1}dx$$
$$v = \int{x^{-1}dx = }\ln{x} \qquad du = \frac{-s{(\ln{x})^{-s-1}}}{x}dx$$

giving:
$$\int{udv} = (\ln{x})^{-s}\ln{x} - \int{\ln{x}\frac{-s{(\ln{x})^{-s-1}}}{x}}$$

again, integration by parts:

$$\int{\ln{x}\frac{-s{(\ln{x})^{-s-1}}}{x}}dx = \int{udv} = uv - \int{vdu}$$

$$dv = \frac{-s{(\ln{x})^{-s-1}}}{x}dx \qquad u = \ln{x}$$
$$v = \int{\frac{-s{(\ln{x})^{-s-1}}}{x}}dx = \ln{x}^{-s} \qquad du = \frac{1}{x}dx$$

giving:
$$\int{udv} = \ln{x}\ln{x}^{-s} - \int{\ln{x}^{-s}\frac{1}{x}dx}$$
$$ = \ln{x}^{1-s} - \int{\frac{\ln{x}^{-s}}{x}dx} $$

by substitution, let $u = \ln{x}$ and $du = \frac{1}{x}$,

$$ \int{\frac{\ln{x}^{-s}}{x}dx} \to \int{u^{-s}du} = \frac{u^{-s+1}}{1-s}$$
$$ = (\ln{x})^{1-s}(1-s)^{-1}$$

therefore, I get:

$$I = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[(\ln{x})^{1-s} - (\ln{x})^{1-s} + (\ln{x})^{1-s}(1-s)^{-1}\right]^{t}_{1}$$

$$ = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{x})^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]^{t}_{1}$$

... follow through as above

### Attempt 3: Fixing Integral Limits & Final Limit

$$I = \int_{x=1}^{x=\infty}\frac{1}{x(\ln{x})^s}dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\int^{x=t}_{x=1}\frac{(\ln{x})^{-s}}{x}dx$$

let $u = \ln{x}$ and let $du = \frac{1}{x}dx$,

$$ I \to \lim_{t\to\infty}\int^{u=\ln{t}}_{u=\ln{1}}u^{-s}du = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\frac{u^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]^{u=\ln{t}}_{u=0} $$

convert back from $u \to x : x = e^{u}$...

$$ = \lim_{t\to\infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{x})^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]^{x=t}_{x=1} = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{t})^{1-s}}{1-s} - \frac{(\ln{1})^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]$$

$$ = \lim_{t \to \infty}\left[\frac{(\ln{t})^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]$$

- $s<1$ : $I \to \infty$
- $s=1$ : $I = \frac{1}{0}$
- $s>1$ : $(\ln{t})^{1-s} \to 0 \therefore I \to 0$

I have fixed my limit for $s>1$ but can't see the problem with $s<1$

Comment: @Chappers how did you get my title formatted nicely - or can you direct me to a post that shows me how to do it?

Comment: Please revise the conclusion when $s>1$ (and change the formulation when $s=1$).

Comment: a) It's just a case of putting dollar signs around it as in the body. b) If you want to know how anything in a question or answer is formatted, click the edit button and look at the code (not forgetting to click Cancel and not change anything afterwards!).

Comment: When you did the substitution, you did not change the lower limit of integration. And in the original integral, you should be worrying about trouble at the bottom end as well as trouble for big $x$.

Comment: Heroic. But let $u=\ln x$. We are looking at $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{u^s}$. There is trouble at $0$ and infinity. When $0$ is good infinity is bad and vice-versa.  It would be different if the integral were from $2$ to $\infty$. Then $s\gt 1$ is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is the easiest approach. When using substitution, you can also substitute the limits (rather than change the variable back to $x$ at the end). So the limit $x=1$ corresponds to the limit $u=\ln(1)=0$ and the limit $x=\infty$ corresponds to $u=\ln(\infty)=\infty$. The problem you have above is that:

$$
I=\lim_{t \to\infty}\int_{x=1}^{x=t}u^{-s}du=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{u=0}^{u=\infty}u^{-s}du\ne\lim_{t\to\infty}\left[ \frac{u^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]_{0}^{t} \text{ when } s=1
$$

So you need to separate the evaluation of the integral into cases:

$$
I=\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-s}du=\left\{ \begin{array} \\\lim_{t\to\infty} \left[\frac{u^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]_{0}^{t}\text{ , }s\ne1 \\ \lim_{t\to\infty} \left[\ln(u)\right]_{0}^{t}\text{ , }s=1 \end{array}  \right.
$$

Now you can see that for the $s=1$ case you also have a problem at the lower limit as $\ln(0)$ is undefined (as mentioned in the comments). There will also be a problem at the lower limit when $s>2$. In all cases, however, the integral will diverge.

Comment: ah I see, for $s>1$: I was doing the equivalent of, $\lim_{t \to \infty}\left[\frac{0^{-n}}{a}\right] = 0, n \in \Bbb{R}^{+}$ which is clearly incorrect.
I think I should have taken the original integral as $\int_{2}^{\infty}$ as @AndréNicolas mentioned